# Firebase Firestore get user related data

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my Firestore database I have two collections, **users** and **feeds**. Feeds contains data about the field, like comments, followers... etc. The followers data type is a simple (string) array.

My question is, that how can I get every feed where the follower's array contains the user's id? Is there any other way than query all the feeds, and select the related ones in a foreach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to query documents based on the contents of an array field.  From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays):

> Although Cloud Firestore can store arrays, it does not support
>   querying array members or updating single array elements. However, you
>   can still model this kind of data by leveraging the other capabilities
>   of Cloud Firestore.

If you want to query only fields that have a certain follower, you should use an object fields instead of an array.

That same page of documentation goes on to describe the strategy for converting your array to an object.  The object will map user ids to a boolean `true` if they are following that feed.

Answer (score 0):

I think Doug Stevenson's answer is outdated. You can use the field "followers" to store an array of users.

```
feeds: { 
  ...
  followers: ['user_id_1', 'user_id_2', 'user_id_3']
}
```

You can use [Array membership](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership) operators like `array-contains` to filter feeds collection.

Example (Web):

```
feedsRef.where("followers", "array-contains", "user_id_1")
```

You can also use `in` and `array-contains-any` operators as per your requirements.